# Do I need to save NSManagedObjectContext of Main thread concurrency inside a perform block of a private context?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I need an answer from a reliable source, about saving NSManagedObjectContexts. Imagine I have a long writing task in in a global queue, I have two contexts as singleton reference (1 of NSMainQueueConcurrency, the other private)...

I have a large task of writing into database and my code look like this:

```
[privateMOC performBlock^:{
   // Here goes a large writing task
   ................................
   // And here goes saving
   [privateMOC save:nil];
   [mainMOC performBlock^:{
      [mainMOC save:nil];
   }]
}];
```

My question is: is it necessary to call save to main context inside a `performBlock^` of a `privateContext`, and another note is that there is no parent-child context structure, but there are two `NSPersistentStoreCoordinators`.

Thx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, it depends what you want and need. :)

In general there's no requirement for one context's save call to be nested in a block passed to another context. You might want to do that in some cases, though. In your sample code, you guarantee that `[mainMOC save:nil]` won't get called until after `[privateMOC save:nil]` finishes. Is that important? There's not enough detail in your question to say if it matters in your case, so you'll have to consider that for yourself.

While I'm at it though, you **really** need to check the results of your save calls. The method returns a boolean to tell you if saving succeeded, and it can return an `NSError` by reference to tell you why it failed. Your code doesn't check the result and doesn't allow for an `NSError`-- meaning that if saving ever fails, you've ensured that you won't know that it failed or why. Use the information that the framework is trying to give you.

Comment: Well, for one thing, it always succeeds in saving... I'm asking this as a Core Data multi context best practice, please note that this is not parent-child context, because in Apple documentation about concurrencies, it is recommended to save both contexts like this, but in Apple's case, privateMOC is child of mainMOC. There is one edge case with me, because 1 in 1000 times, my app crashes in NSNotification when merging two contexts, that are invoked by saving mainContext in this code sample, but I am asking is it save to remove saveMainContext in my code sample without any serious problems? :)

Comment: @miljan I think I covered that as well as possible with the limited details provided.

Comment: I will go without saving mainContext in block, concurrency debug flag passes, for now there are no problems :) We'll see.. My only fear is potential data loss if something happens, because for instance, there are times when my app creates 300 background threads, each one doing this simultaneously...